# Hostname not changing (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

When I set up a VPS, I set the name to "main" so both my /etc/hosts and /etc/hostnames files had one entry (that being "main"). So I set up root ssh access and type "hostname" and it gives me "main". Same deal when I type "hostname -f".

Well, I'm trying to set up Exim4 to send mail from my Django app (I only need to send, not receive) and I added the following to `/etc/hosts`.

```
127.0.1.1 main.mydomain.com main
<myip> main.mydomain.com main
```

I then executed `service hostname restart` and `hostname -f` only returned `main`. I even rebooted (something I try to avoid doing) and it still comes back `main`. Not sure why this is...  The actual files themselves show my new entries but I can't get the actual `hostname` or `hostname -f` command to change for the life of me.

I'm guessing, but I'm not 100% sure, that's why when I use the command `echo test message | mail -s test email@email.com` I'm not getting an email at `email@email.com` (too many emails?). If it isn't absolutely necessary to have hostnames set up to use exim, I'd like to avoid it because its caused me such a headache.

Any help will render me eternally grateful to your awesomeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the domainname, you can use the equally named program `domainname`:

```
sudo domainname example.com
```

To query the actually set value, call it without parameters.

Also add need run the `hostname.sh` script (depends on the OS) to make the changes effective:

```
/etc/init.d/hostname.sh
```

On Debian and derivatives, there is also `/etc/mailname` which should contain the default sender's domain for outgoing emails.

I can't make a statement on Exim, but I think the default values in exim for host- and domainame should point to the OS's settings.

To cite the manpage of hostname:

> THE FQDN
>
> You can't change the FQDN (as returned by hostname --fqdn) or the DNS
>   domain name (as returned by dnsdomainname) with this command. The FQDN
>   of  the  system is the name that the resolver(3) returns for the host
>   name.
>
> Technically: The FQDN is the name getaddrinfo(3) returns for the host
>   name returned by gethostname(2).  The DNS domain name is the part
>   after the first dot.
>
> Therefore it depends on the configuration (usually in /etc/host.conf)
>   how you can change it. Usually (if the hosts file is parsed before DNS
>   or NIS) you can change it in /etc/hosts.

Comment: This seems more difficult than it should be.  So I have to set the /etc/hosts and /etc/hostnames file plus do the sudo domainname thing?         

Will, at that point, Exim work as intended (assuming all my configuration settings are correct)?

Comment: @BrianBurgess I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks.  I'll see how it works.  As long as I can change that, I can at least move in to figuring out the configuration.

Comment: I praise your awesome for it is great.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If mail is being sent via postfix then you should also edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to have the correct value for `myhostname = xyz`